# Underdetermined systems solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm given the following problem: Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $m<n$, rank($A$) $= m$. Given $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$ we want to find $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax = b$.

Describe an algorithm for solving this problem using the following scheme. **Assume $x = A^Ty$**. Describe **why** and **how** you can use this assumption to solve for x.

**Motivation**: Here are my thoughts on this: we talked in class about how you could use the reduced SVD of $A$ to solve this problem, leading to $x = V\Sigma^{-1} U^Tb$, but for large $A$, finding the SVD could be expensive, so we want an alternative.

**Why can we assume this**: We can say $x = A^Ty$ because, looking at the solution by SVD, we note that $x$ is in the range of $V$ and thus it is in the row space of $A$, so there is some $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $x=A^Ty$.

**How this helps**: We can rewrite the original equation now as $AA^Ty = b$. I think this is more helpful because now $AA^T$ is a full rank, square, symmetric matrix. However, this is where I'm a bit unsure about how helpful this is/why this is a much easier problem to solve. $AA^T$ could still be rather large so I'm not sure if we should thinking about other algorithms that could be used from here or what.

Any thoughts or leading questions on this would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Write $S = AA^T$, so we have the system $Sy = b$ with $S$ being invertible (full rank) and symmetric. In this situation there is a unique solution, namely, $y = S^{-1}b$. You can use the famous Gaussian Elimination to solve this system. Gaussian Elimination is a reasonable algorithm in this case. Its cost is $\frac{2}{3}m^3 + O(m^2)$. Compare with the algorithm to compute the SVD, which costs $4n^2m - \frac{4}{3}n^3 + O(n^2)$.

Comment: Okay awesome, thanks! Can I ask whether the rest of my answers make sense as well?